# Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech is not working after publishing application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

Getting following exception when loading :

```
speechRecognizer = new Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechRecognizer(config);
```

> Inner exception : InnerException = {"Unable to load DLL
>   'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.bindings.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)"}
>
> Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.carbon_csharpPINVOKE.SpeechConfig_FromSubscription(String
>   jarg1, String jarg2)    at
>   Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(String
>   subscription, String region)    at
>   Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(String
>   subscriptionKey, String region) |ERROR|The type initializer for
>   'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception. 2019-01-03
>   16:02:50.2178|ERROR|The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.carbon_csharpPINVOKE'
>   threw an exception.

Comment: 1. Make sure you've installed the [`Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech)  2. If you're using the `DOTNET Core`, the `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.bindings.dll` should be copied into directory of `publish/runtimes/<your-platform>/native/` automatically when you run `dotnet publish`.  3. If you're using the `.NET Framework`, the `bindings.dll` resides in `\bin\x64\Debug`  or  `\bin\x64\Release`  folder.

Comment: @itminus Thanks a lot. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, you are missing "Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.bindings.dll" . You have to include the dll in the project and mark it as part of the deploy. Make sure it appears in the deployed folder in the IIS , copy it manually as last option.

Comment: I have already searched for that dll but didn't found anywhere, can you please let me know from where i can get that dll.

Comment: I have never used that service, but it should be part of the CognitiveServices SDK, try searching it here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/ or here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/#pivot=sdkstools

Comment: Have you seen the document below [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-csharp-dotnet-windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-csharp-dotnet-windows) and the gitbub repo [https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk), they have samples for CognitiveServices